# Tic Tac Toe Issues Appending User Input To Board Using Index Positions

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am building a basic tic tac toe game (New to coding!)

I created a board and am trying to append the user input to the game board. The idea is to match the index position of the user input as an integer to the index position on the board. I currently have the script printing the board and accepting the input, but it will not append to the board. Code is below (I have excluded the game logic for now) (Assuming the issue is in the board placement function and while game loop):

```
board = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']

def print_board(board):
    print('    ','|','    ','|','    ')
    print('  '+board[7],' |  '+board[8],'  |  '+board[9])
    print('    ','|','    ','|','    ')
    print('_________________')
    print('    ','|','    ','|','    ')
    print('  '+board[4],' |  '+board[5],'  |  '+board[6])
    print('    ','|','    ','|','    ')
    print('_________________')
    print('    ','|','    ','|','    ')
    print('  '+board[1],' |  '+board[2],'  |  '+board[3])
    print('    ','|','    ','|','    ')
    
def player_input():
    selection = ''
    accept_range = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    
    while selection not in accept_range:
        player1 = int(input('Player 1: Pick a number 1 through 9 on your keypad to put an X on the board: '))
        player2 = int(input('Player 2: Pick a number 1 through 9 on your keypad to put an O on the board: '))
        
        if player1 not in accept_range:
            print('Please enter another number 1-9')
        else:
            player2
            
def board_placement():
    if player1 in accept_range:
        return board.append[player1]('X')
    else 
        if player2 in accept_range:
        return board.append[player2]('O')

game = True 

while game:
    #Print Board
    board = print_board(board)
    #Ask for An Initial Response
    position = player_input()
    #Place response 
    placement = board_placement(board)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with your code. `while selection not in accepted_range` will never repeat because you are never updating `selection`. You also are not `return`ing anything from `player_input`, so `position` will be set to `None`. In `board_placement`, you need to pass in `player1` and `player2` as parameters. You are also assinging the result of `print_board` to board, which is `None` because it doesn't return anything. Same problem with `board_placement`. Also append will add an item to a list, when here you are just trying to modify the list at a spectific index. Here, I have modified your code

```
board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']


def print_board(board):
    print('    ', '|', '    ', '|', '    ')
    print('  ' + board[7], ' |  ' + board[8], '  |  ' + board[8])
    print('    ', '|', '    ', '|', '    ')
    print('_________________')
    print('    ', '|', '    ', '|', '    ')
    print('  ' + board[4], ' |  ' + board[5], '  |  ' + board[6])
    print('    ', '|', '    ', '|', '    ')
    print('_________________')
    print('    ', '|', '    ', '|', '    ')
    print('  ' + board[1], ' |  ' + board[2], '  |  ' + board[3])
    print('    ', '|', '    ', '|', '    ')


def player_input():
    accept_range = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    player1 = player2 = ''
    while player1 not in accept_range:
        player1 = int(input('Player 1: Pick a number 1 through 9 on your keypad to put an X on the board: '))
    while player2 not in accept_range:
        player2 = int(input('Player 1: Pick a number 1 through 9 on your keypad to put an O on the board: '))

    return player1, player2

def board_placement(player1, player2):
    # we know player1 and player2 will be in accept_range because of player_input
    board[player1] = 'X'
    board[player2] = 'O'


game = True

while game:
    # Print Board
    print_board(board)
    # Ask for An Initial Response
    player1, player2 = player_input()
    # Place response
    board_placement(player1, player2)
```